# Using two independent paths in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently using React Router and have routes that use the browserHistory, for example:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRedirect, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="tasks" component={Tasks}>
    <IndexRoute component={List} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={Item} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Which allows me to do routes such as:

- `/tasks/`
- `/tasks/1234`

This works, but we have come across a situation where we have two views that are displayed at the same time. We'd like for the link to be shareable and have the app open with both views.

So for example, if we have tasks on the left side of the screen, and a shop  on the right, we'd like for there to be two independent parts of the path, something like:

- `/tasks/1234/#/shop/item/xyz`

The shop route should be independent of the left of the hash, and the tasks route should be independent of the right of the hash, so that `/new-feature/xyz/#/shop/item/xyz` should still render the same view on the right side of the window.

Is it possible to have React Router do routes like this? Or will I have to write a custom router to solve this?

I'm guessing I'd basically have to combine the browserHistory and hashHistory together, but I don't think that's possible with React Router out of the box.

Comment: `/tasks/1234/#/shop/item/xyz` looks just like a regular nested route to me? Are there other configurations of this url that would break just a normal nested structure like that?

Comment: agree calling out for nested routes, one to handle the side panel then the other to handle the inner pages etc?

Comment: @azium, a nested route would require `/shop` to be nested under `/tasks`.  I believe OP wants each part to be independent of the other so that you can navigate out of `/tasks` but remain at `/shop` (for the left and right part of the page respectively).

Comment: Yeah I don't think react-router supports anything other than linear view hierarchies. The closest I can think of would be to have a route with a `left` and `right` query param that encodes the state for the left and right view. It will then be up to you to render the correct view when the route is changed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something that @Chris mentioned. I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think rolling your own router just to handle this case might be a little overboard. You can have as many different paths in your route config as you want, and access param information in your components:

```jsx
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
  <Route path="/tasks/:taskId" component={App} />
  <Route path="/shop/:shopId" component={App} />
  <Route path="/tasks/:taskId/shop/:shopId" component={App} />
</Router>

let App = ({ params }) => // simplified
  <div>
    { params.shopId && <Shop /> }
    { params.taskId && <List /> }
  </div>
```

Just a thought.. I think there are several ways to augment this to handle more complex scenarios but this would definitely work for what you've specified in the question (for the most part).

Update: Above is 'hardcoded', but of course you do not need to write out every combination by hand. This is what loops are for.

```jsx
import * as routeComponents from './routeComponents'

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  { routeComponents.map(r => <Route {...r} />) }
</Router>

let App = ({ params }) => 
  <div>
    { routeComponents.reduce((matches, r) => ([
        ...components,
        ...(params[r.slug] ? [r.component] : [])
    ]), [])}
  </div>
```

Comment: But this is just a simple case where there are 2 features, which means 3 different routes. If there are many features, we have to write all of the combinations out; not to mention all the nested routes.

Comment: You definitely do not need to write them all out, but you do need to describe it someway, like have a folder with an index file that stores your route components. Updated my answer... if you really want I can make a fiddle out of this too with some nested routes and all that jazz.

Comment: Also I think if it turns out this is not enough, I would consider making a pull request against React Router over starting from scratch. :)

Answer (score 0):

We have developed our own router [Boring Router](https://github.com/makeflow/boring-router) with "parallel routing" support, though it depends on **MobX** and works differently with React Router in many ways.

In Boring Router, a parallel route is stored as query string parameter prefixed with `_`. E.g., `/app/workbench?_sidebar=/achievements`.

Check out a complete example [here](https://github.com/makeflow/boring-router/blob/master/packages/boring-router-react/examples/parallel-routes/main.tsx).